# How should I understand the mechanism of matrix decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, linear-transformations, mathematical-modeling

I want to understand how matrix decomposition works. I see matrix decomposition almost everywhere. But based on what theory or principle, we can decompose the matrix is not seen to me. I want to get the understanding of when we can decompose the matrix.

Comment: A matrix decomposition is just a way to express a matrix as the product of simpler matrices.

Comment: But still what is the meaning of simpler matrices?

Comment: That depends on the decomposition. For example, the LU decomposition expresses a matrix as the product of a lower triangular matrix and an upper triangular matrix. The singular value decomposition expresses a matrix as the product of two orthogonal matrices and a diagonal matrix.

Comment: To give another example, in geometric optics, the Gauss decomposition expresses any non-telescopic optical system, no matter how complex, in terms of three basic parameters: the position of the two principal planes and the focal length, which are expressed in the three matrices of the decomposition.